# Hiding HTML element in Android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I saw the related topic but I could not get it to function.

I need to remove a search bar and a navigation dropdown from a web view I am using.

My code is below.

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
    {  
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
            "document.getElementsById('omc-main-navigation')[0].style.display = 'none'; " +  
            "})()");  
    }  
});  

webView.loadUrl(links.get(arg2));
```

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that DOES not work...
Any ideas?

Comment: webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "elem = document.getElementByName('mobi-search'); if (elem) {elem.style.display = 'none; ';})()");

  Just tried this and got nothing aswell... is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any method like `document.getElementsById()`.

Use

```
document.getElementById()
```

instead of the

```
document.getElementsById() // "s" is extra here.
```

It should work.